# In IE8 JQuery.isFunction does not report document.write to be a function

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sinon

I tried **jQuery.isFunction(document.write)** in IE8 and it returned **false**.

These are a few things I noticed.
1. **document.write.constructor** is **undefined**
2. **typeof document.write** is **object**

I came to know this issue when creating a stub on document.write using Sinon which threw an exception saying **Attempted to wrap object property write as function**

Though, I can workaround this issue, by bypassing the check for document.write specifically, but I just wanted to know whether its a bug in JQuery or its intentional(though it seems not).

Also, I checked the JQuery code and its a simple check **$.call(a) === "[object Function]"** which fails in case of IE8(most probably other versions).

One more thing, why can't we just check whether **call** function of document.write is **defined and native**? This should suffice or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/c1f546f6-d7e1-4b46-a1c9-8f02eaf1286b) , this question was discessed at msdn forum.
2. And here [why-dhtml-behavior-not-work-in-ie8-if-document-write-is-executed-in-head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593913/why-dhtml-behavior-not-work-in-ie8-if-document-write-is-executed-in-head)